# How to Add void Promise and other type promise to single Promise All Array

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I have `Promise.all` that works on all `promise<void>` like this

```
var actionList = new Array<Promise<void>>();

actionList.push(PluginService.InstallExtension(element, en.ExtensionFolder)
    .then(function () {
        addedExtensions.push(element);
        var name = element.publisher + '.' + element.name + '-' + element.version;
        //vscode.window.showInformationMessage("Extension " + name + " installed Successfully");
    }));

Promise.all(actionList).then(function () {
    // all resolved
}).catch(function (e) {
    console.error(e);
});
```

I want to add `Promise<boolean>` in `actionList`

How i can add in typescript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) on the type parameter and specify that it can be void or a boolean:

```
var actionList = new Array<Promise<void | boolean>>();

// example of compiling code:
actionList.push(new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {}));
actionList.push(new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {}));
```